# Executing the bat file before starting the iis site

Tags: python, django, iis

My django application uses environment variables that must be set via a bat file. How to do it via python (for example via subprocess) I do not know because when executing a bat file via python, a new process is created in which environment variables are set, but when the process ends, all environment variables disappear and they are not reflected in the creator process. My django server is running on IIS. Perhaps you should configure IIS somehow so that it executes first .bat file and then launched my django project and this django project inherited all the environment variables that it created .bat file.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to do this in iis.

Comment: is it possible to do this in a Django application?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Django.

Comment: Since you use things like HttpPlatformHandler to launch Django or Flask web apps on IIS, https://halfblood.pro/running-flask-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/, you can write your own launcher script and set `processPath` and `arguments` to control what to do during initialization.